# How to find contours in a region of interest in image using opencv and Python?

Tags: python

```
while(True):

    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    a, b = 0, 0

    height, width, layers = frame.shape
    start_height = height - height
    left_x = width - 500

    #right_area = frame[y:y+height, x:x+300]
    #left_area = frame[y:y+height,]

    black_min = np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)
    black_max = np.array([179, 255, 70], np.uint8)

    red_min = np.array([0, 70, 50], np.uint8)
    red_max = np.array([20, 255, 255], np.uint8)

    red1 = np.array([170, 70, 50], np.uint8)
    red2 = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)

    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red1, red2)
    red_mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_min, red_max)
    kernel = np.ones((7, 7), "uint8")

    red_mask = cv2.dilate(red_mask, kernel)
    res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=red_mask)
    red_mask2 = cv2.dilate(red_mask2, kernel)
    res_red2 = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=red_mask2)

    area1 = frame[a:a + height, b:b + 300]
    area2 = frame[a:a + height, left_x:left_x + 500]

    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(red_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


    for pic, c in enumerate(cnts):

        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if (700 > area > 350):
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x + w, y + h),(0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "Red detected", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 0, 255))


    cv2.imshow("Video from camera", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I belive that for C++ the solution looks like this:

findContours(Mask(cv::Rect(x,y,width,height)), contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
Point(0,0) );

How can I change this line to get the results I want?

this is the area I'm interested in frame[a:a + height, b:left_x + 300] Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you write what do you mean?

Comment: Its my fist program in Qt, firstly i draw than i save points now i try to read and draw them

Comment: I think if i will change QRect i will need to change everinthing what i did already drawing and saving points

Comment: sure, I am very appriciate for your help!

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks strange to me, here a snippet with a line

```
QString line="144,81:626,232";
QStringList points = line.split(":");
qDebug()<< points[0];
qDebug()<< points[1];
QRectF rectangle;
QStringList xy1 = points[0].split(",");
qDebug()<< xy1[0];
qDebug()<< xy1[1];
auto x1=QString(xy1[0]).toFloat();
auto y1=QString(xy1[1]).toFloat();

rectangle.setTopLeft(QPointF(x1,y1));

xy1 = points[1].split(",");
qDebug()<< xy1[0];
qDebug()<< xy1[1];
x1=QString(xy1[0]).toFloat();
y1=QString(xy1[1]).toFloat();

rectangle.setBottomRight(QPointF(x1,y1));

qDebug() << "Rec: " << rectangle;
return 0;
```

so for the input `"144,81:626,232";` you get the output:

```
Rec:  QRectF(144,81 482x151)
```

because that is the way qt print rectangle objects-> `topLeftPoint wxh`

Answer (score 1):

**Why do you get QRectF(324,16 -241x125) for "324,16:83,141?"**

You are misinterpreting the output of `qDebug`. The first part is the origin, which is the same as the top-left point. The second part however is the size, not the bottom-right point as you think. Setting the bottom right point to `83, 141`, as you do, results in a size of `83 - 324 = -241` and `141 - 16 = 125`. That is why you get `QRectF(324,16 -241x125)` as an output.

To fix this, use [`QRectF::setSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html#setSize) insetad of `QRectF::setBottom` like that:

```
setSize(QPointF(xy2.at(0).toFloat(), xy2.at(1).toFloat()));
```

**Why do you get `QRectF(0,0 0x0)`?**

In the second constructor of `RectToDraw` you call `readFromString`, where you make the following check:

```
if(point.count()!=2) return;
```

If this check fails, it would made sense to skip creating the rectangle. This would be the case, if `readFromString` were a helper function somewhere. But in your case your `QRectF` is **already constructed** (because `RectToDraw` is a subclass of `QRectF`), though without valid coordinates, hence you get those invalid rectangles `QRectF(0,0 0x0)`.

As a side note, classes like `QPoint` and `QRect`, resp. `QPointF` and `QRectF` are lightweight classes, meant to hold data. And yet you try to assing more responsibilities to them, subclassing `QRectF` and let `RectToDraw` know how to extract its coordinates from a string. From one side this does not make sense, since when you draw a rectangle on a sheet of paper it does not care if you draw it with a pencil, or a pen, but the shape, the size and the position is what actually matters. From another side your approach poses a design problem, which leads to the aforementioned errors. With regard to this, I highly suggest you to rethink the design of your application.